# JOOQ - inline Converter not being applied

Tags: java, sql, enums, jooq

In my `build.gradle` I use a converter in my `forcedTypes`. This works fine where i need it.

```
forcedType {
    userType = 'java.util.List<stormsensor.thor.dto.telemetry.FlowEventType>'
    converter = 'stormsensor.thor.config.jooq.StringToFlowEventTypeListConverter'
    includeExpression = '.*\\.FLOW_EVENTS'
    includeTypes = '.*'
}
```

However, I am trying to convert a comma separated string into a list of enums for a specificuse case:

```
DataType<List<FlowEventType>> LIST_TYPE = SQLDataType.VARCHAR.asConvertedDataType(new StringToFlowEventTypeListConverter());

ctx.select(
  groupConcatDistinct(NOTIFICATION_RULE.FLOW_EVENT_TYPE).as(field(name("notifications"), LIST_TYPE))
)
.from(NOTIFICATION_RULE)
.groupBy(MONITORING_POINT_ID)
.fetchInto(BatchNotificationRuleModel.class);
```

This throws an exception

```
org.jooq.exception.MappingException: An error ocurred when mapping record to class stormsensor.thor.dto.notification.batch.BatchNotificationRuleModel
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper$MutablePOJOMapper.map(DefaultRecordMapper.java:802)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper.map(DefaultRecordMapper.java:500)
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultImpl.into(ResultImpl.java:1284)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchInto(AbstractResultQuery.java:1550)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetchInto(SelectImpl.java:3746)
    at stormsensor.thor.repository.notification.BatchNotificationRuleRepositoryJdbcImpl.save(BatchNotificationRuleRepositoryJdbcImpl.java:98)
Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from CRITICAL_DEPTH,NON_TIDAL_CSO (class java.lang.String) to interface java.util.List
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.fail(Convert.java:1194)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.from(Convert.java:1083)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert0(Convert.java:324)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:316)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:387)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.get(AbstractRecord.java:275)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper$MutablePOJOMapper.map(DefaultRecordMapper.java:830)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper$MutablePOJOMapper.map(DefaultRecordMapper.java:762)
    ... 72 more
```

This is the model I am fetching into:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BatchNotificationRuleModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<FlowEventType> notifications;
    private List<MessageProtocolType> protocols;
}
```

Am I missing something?

UPDATE:

I am able to convert inline using

```
//...
.groupBy(MONITORING_POINT_ID)
.fetchStream().map(e -> {
    Converter<String, List<FlowEventType>> converter = new StringToFlowEventTypeListConverter();
    List<FlowEventType> notifications = e.get(field(name("notifications"), String.class), converter);
    return BatchNotificationRuleModel.builder().notifications(notifications).build();
}).collect(toList());
```

What is the difference between the initial converter I apply vs the late stage map conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it seems reasonable to expect that [`Field.as(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#as(org.jooq.Field)) would use the argument field's name *and* type for type coercion, this is not the case. As per the Javadoc:

> Create an alias for this field based on another field's name.

In order to coerce your expression to the desired data type, you have to do this, manually:

```java
groupConcatDistinct(NOTIFICATION_RULE.FLOW_EVENT_TYPE)
  .coerce(LIST_TYPE)
  .as("notifications")
```

See [`Field.coerce(DataType)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#coerce(org.jooq.DataType))